# How do I plot this graph in octave?

Tags: functions, octave

Trying to plot this graph in octave, do anyone know how to do it? I do not know how to do it when it is equal to 0.

$r^{3}(1 + \frac{0.00822}{101325 * r}) - r(\frac{6 \pi * (16.7 * 10^{-6}) * (1.6666 * 10^{-9})}{\frac{4}{3} \pi * 859.9 * 9.82}) = 0$

Comment: That does not look like a curve, but instead a cubic in $r$ with $r=0$ as one of the solutions after expanding the first half of the expression, so in effect a quadratic equation

Comment: Sorry, yes that is correct.

Comment: If you plot this equation you get a few points. Do you mean a curve like $y = x^3 (1+c/x) -dx$ where $x,y$ are variables, and $c,d$ some constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot this equation you get a few points. I think you plotting the curve $y = x^3 (1+c/x) -dx$ where $x,y$ are variables, and $c,d$ some constants.

```
c = 0.00822/101325
d = ...
x = linspace(-5,5,100);            %left bound, right bound, number of points in between
y= x.^3 .* (1 + c./x) - d.*x; % .-operators for element wise operations
plot(x,y)
```